# JavaFX focus listener between stages

Tags: javafx, modal-dialog, tableview, focus, stage

I'm developing a Java application where I have a main stage (first) consisting of a lot of buttons, each of them opens another modal (second) window where I can insert/modify/delete some data read from my DB and visualize the current status of the DB showing data in a TableView that I fill in the initialize() method of that particular controller. When the "add" button is pressed another modal (the third) is open to enter some data.

What i would like is to refresh the data displayed on the second modal (where the table is) to immediatly keep trace of the newly added data. At the moment this doesn't happen (of course) because the second stage is still displaying the data that i retrieve from DB before the new addition, so I have to close and reopen the second stage to effectivly see the result.

There's a way to "do something" in a stage after re-gain the focus by closing the third stage?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `showAndWait`. Probably setting the table's window as the owner window of the new stage. This way you could actually "return" something from the new window. `Dialog` may also be worth a look...

Comment: Or use `thirdStage.setOnHidden(...)`. Or, pass the table's `items` list to the controller for the third window, and update it directly from there.